# Application is crashed after activity is called

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class NewAct extends Activity 
{

private OnClickListener EnterValue=new OnClickListener()
    {   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        EditText E1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Total);
        String value=E1.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(NewAct.this,PlayClass.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("TotalMatchSticks", value);  
              //Add the bundle to the intent
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entervalue);

    Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    enter.setOnClickListener(EnterValue);

}
}
```

I have also added this line in Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".PlayClass" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

This NEWAct activity is crashing.And this is the LogCat values:

> 06-22 12:24:54.392: WARN/dalvikvm(755): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 06-22 12:24:54.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-22 12:24:54.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matchsticks/com.matchsticks.PlayClass}:

Comment: you should provide logs about the exception from LogCat

Comment: For one, you can edit your question, so you don't have to post extra information in comments.  Second, if you really want help, you should post the stack trace and actually tell us which activity is crashing.  Is it the one that you posted the code for or the one you mentioned having in your Manifest?

Comment: Please edit your question with full stacktrace because the part you have given says nothing

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use below code.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(NewAct.this,PlayClass.class);
intent.putExtras("TotalMatchSticks", value);  
startActivity(intent);
```